# MySQL Query not submitting to database, No Errors

Tags: php, mysql

For some reason, this query isn't submitting to the database, although there are no errors!

```
$listingdesc2 = "'test test test','test test test'";
$category = "apple, banana";
$addlisting = mysql_query("INSERT INTO `directory` (". $category .") VALUES (". $listingdesc2 .")");
```

I have made sure the table and column names are correct. Is there something wrong with my query, or not?

I am thinking it is something to do with `$listingdesc2`, trying to use a variable in a query that is seperated by commas.

apple should return 'test test test' in the database
banana should return 'test test test' in the database

chris, here's a full snippet of my code, the above was a really basic example.

```
$listingdesc = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['listingdesc']); 
$category = $_POST['category']; //this is an array from a multiple selection checklist
$numcat = count($category);
$category = implode(", ",$category);
$listingdesc1 = "'$listingdesc'";
$a = array_fill(0, $numcat, $listingdesc1);
$listingdesc2 = implode(',', $a);

$addlisting = mysql_query("INSERT INTO `directory` (". $category .") VALUES (". $listingdesc2 .")");
```

Then I echo the values used in the query, they are as follows:

`$listingdesc2 = 'test test test','test test test'`

`$category = 'apple, banana'`

Comment: FYI for the comma(,) in the values mysql query is not running successfully.

Comment: How can I get around this?

Comment: Just escape the comma character and it will fine.

Comment: `mysql_real_escape_string` on the entire `$listingdesc2`? Where am I missing quotes, Jon? Thanks

Comment: Use http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-error.php. Does the page generate anything?

Comment: replace comma(,) with (\,) backslash comma

Comment: can you post more codes plz. may be problem somewhere else

Comment: @BikashP why do that?

Comment: To escape comma character in mysql @chris85

Comment: @BikashP yes, I read your comment. Why escape the comma? It is separating the two columns.

Comment: Escaping doesn't work, as the query would then look like `VALUES (\'test test test\',\'test1 test1 test1\')`

Comment: It will remain as comma and will be inserted as comma in table.use just to escape mysql query .

Comment: Maybe the problem is just the syntax of the INSERT statement.

Comment: @BikashP No, it won't. Please read up on SQL syntax. There are 2 columns and 2 strings be inserted into them.

Comment: the query is essentially just `mysql_query("INSERT INTO directory (apple, banana) VALUES ('test test test','test1 test1 test1')");` so I don't understand?

Comment: @RyanButterworth Have you used `mysql_` functions before? Is the page returning a 200 or 500?

Comment: @chris85 No http status codes returned, I do a header redirect at the end of the page and store `$category` and `$listingdesc2` into session data, then output it on the page I redirect to, and it's all fine! But it just doesn't insert into the database :(

Comment: Stop redirecting and check for errors on the query execution. Output the query on the page and make sure it is as expected.

Comment: Okay so I removed redirection, and tried using this to check for errors: `if (!$addlisting) {
    die('Invalid query: ' . mysql_error());
}`, the page outputs 'Invalid query:' with no error message?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/111653/discussion-between-chris85-and-ryan-butterworth).

Answer (score 0):

With `string mysql_escape_string ( string $unescaped_string )` you can escape especial characters  just for prevent sql injection , by the way I consider you to use `PDO` library from PHP or `mysqli` instead of `mysql` , because this library is deprecated in `PHP >5.4` and now the stable version of `PHP is 5.6`.

Comment: Why do commas need to be escaped? There's nothing that needs to be escaped in current query..

Comment: Well yes is more for escapes special characters, I will edit my post, thank you